# ComboBox doesn't show the data

Tags: c#, visual-studio, combobox, userform

ComboBox doesn't show the data, I populate my combobox with data from my database this way:

```
private void PartDefective(string id)
{
    cmd = new SQLiteCommand("Select * FROM Part_defective where testers = '" + id + "'", DBcon);
    if (DBcon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        DBcon.Open();
    myDA = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
    myDataSet = new DataSet();
    myDA.Fill(myDataSet, "comboBox6");
    this.comboBox6.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables["comboBox6"].DefaultView;
    this.comboBox6.ValueMember = "Part";
    this.comboBox6.DisplayMember = "Part";
    this.comboBox6.SelectedItem = "ID";
    this.comboBox6.SelectedIndex = -1;

    DBcon.Close();
}
```

And to show the data from the database I used :

```
private void comboBox6_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.comboBox6.SelectedValue == null)
    {
        testerid = "1";
    }
    else
    {
      part = this.comboBox6.SelectedText.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on this line:  this.comboBox6.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables["comboBox6"].DefaultView;

Comment: you are open to **Sql injection** use parametrized queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a breakpoint on this line:

```
this.comboBox6.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables["comboBox6"].DefaultView;
```

And then look at the value of myDataSet.Tables["comboBox6"] in the watch or quickwatch window.  Are there any rows?

Also change your code:

```
string sql = "Select * FROM Part_defective where testers = '" + id + "'";
cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, DBcon);
```

Put a breakpoint there, see what the value of sql is.

Manually run the sql against your database and see if there are any results.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no reason to define the `SelectedItem` or `SelectedIndex`. 
The `SelectedIndexChanged Event` is also completely redundant for displaying your combobox.

Remove these lines and see if it solved your problem.

```
this.comboBox6.SelectedItem = "ID";
this.comboBox6.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

If the combobox is still empty, the root of problem has to be with the fetching of your data and filling the datasource.